# Alternative to skiprows when writing to TXT with .to_csv()

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

Is there any similar alternative to `skiprows` when using `.read_csv()`, in order to append a `dataframe` to an existing .txt file with `.to_csv()`, from specific row?

Comment: Adding a block inside a csv file is best achived through creating a new dataframe and saving it with `.to_csv()`. A positional export would have required  a lot of tuning, it does not exist, to my knowledge.

Comment: Hi Evgeny. Thank you for your answer. Nonetheless, I am not sure whether that is my problem or not. I know with `.to_csv()` you can write your dataframe on an existing .txt file. The problem is that you overwrite/erase all data that exist on it. Then, there is another option `mode = 'a'` which allows you to append your dataframe to existing file. My question is whether you can append your dataframe from specific row (removing everything below that row).

Comment: No, you can't, you have to create a new frame and overwrite for this result.